# Move menu CSS slider from left to right side

Tags: html, css

how can I move this pure CSS menu example slider to the right?
When I do "right: 0;" it will not help. I hope you do understand what I'm trying to do.
I can imagine, this problem must have been discussed already, but I can't find a satisfying answer.

Thanks

CodePen example code:

https://codepen.io/tonkec/pen/Ogzpqz

Example HTML:

```
<main>
  <aside>
    <ul class="asideList">
      <li><a href="" class="asideAnchor">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="" class="asideAnchor">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="" class="asideAnchor">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="" class="asideAnchor">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
  <section>
    <input type="checkbox" id="myInput">
    <label for="myInput">
      <span class="bar top"></span>
      <span class="bar middle"></span>
      <span class="bar bottom"></span>
    </label>

    <div class="content">
      <h1>Pure CSS side reveal effect</h1>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>

<a href="https://codepen.io/tonkec" class="ua" target="_blank">
  <i class="fa fa-user"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick.
To move right, you have to

1. move the button itself right
2. move the menu links right
3. change the main content translate direction to left

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

main {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

aside {
  background-color: #0799d3;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 20%;
  z-index: 1;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
  z-index: 3;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
}

.bar {
  display: block;
  background-color: #0799d3;
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  transition: background-color .5s ease-in, transform .5s ease-in, width .5s ease-in;
}

.content {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: transform .5s ease-in-out;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.asideList {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
}

.asideAnchor {
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
  padding: 20px 0;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: relative;
  transition: color .3s .15s ease-in;
}

.asideAnchor::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 0;
  transition: width .3s ease-in;
  z-index: -1;
}

.asideAnchor:hover {
  color: #0799d3;
}

.asideAnchor:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .content {
  transform: translateX(-20%);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label .bar {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label .top {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) rotateZ(45deg);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0px) rotateZ(45deg);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0px) rotateZ(45deg);
  -o-transform: translateY(0px) rotateZ(45deg);
  transform: translateY(0px) rotateZ(45deg);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label .bottom {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px) rotateZ(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-15px) rotateZ(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-15px) rotateZ(-45deg);
  -o-transform: translateY(-15px) rotateZ(-45deg);
  transform: translateY(-15px) rotateZ(-45deg);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label .middle {
  width: 0;
}

.middle {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.ua {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  color: #0799d3;
  font-size: 2em;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <aside>
    <ul class="asideList">
      <li><a href="" class="asideAnchor">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="" class="asideAnchor">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="" class="asideAnchor">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="" class="asideAnchor">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
  <section>
    <input type="checkbox" id="myInput">
    <label for="myInput">
      <span class="bar top"></span>
      <span class="bar middle"></span>
      <span class="bar bottom"></span>
    </label>

    <div class="content">
      <h1>Pure CSS side reveal effect</h1>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>

<a href="https://codepen.io/tonkec" class="ua" target="_blank">
  <i class="fa fa-user"></i></a>
```